# EcmaScript 5 browser implementation

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecma262, ecmascript-5

So Safari and Chrome have started in their betas to implement some ES5 stuff.
For instance Object.create is in them.

Do any of you know if there is a website that shows the progress made in the browsers?
ATM i need to use Object.freeze, and wanted to see which browsers (if any) supported that yet.

Comment: Ok made some tests of Object.freeze in the nightlies of firefox and webkit, the dev version of opera and chrome and none of them yet support Object.freeze

I did how ever see it on the webkit issue tracker so soon i guess :)

Still would be nice with a updated website that shows the current implementation of ES5 in all the browsers

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's an up to date list for major engines: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/