# How to stopPropagation() w/ Hammer.js 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js, stoppropagation

I have a parent and child div.  Panning/dragging on the child should not affect the parent.  [This is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019868/stoppropagation-with-tap-event) but was asked a year ago, and I'm using a newer version of Hammer.js w/ the jQuery wrapper.

My assumption was that I'd have to somehow stopPropagation() but I'm not really sure how to use it.

I've mocked up [a demo showing my problem on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3a25pvn/).  I've also commented out the couple things I've tried.

```
$(".outer-box").hammer().bind("panright", function(event){
    // do stuff when panning
    // panning here should move both boxes
});
$(".outer-box").hammer().bind("panend", function(event){
    // do stuff when panning ends
});

$(".inner-box").hammer().bind("panright", function(event){
    // do stuff when panning
    // panning here should only affect the inner box
});
$(".inner-box").hammer().bind("panend", function(event){
    // do stuff when panning ends
});
```

Any suggestions or tips?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

In Hammer 2.0.6, as others have answered, you can call `event.srcEvent.stopPropagation()`. One caveat, you have to set `domEvents=true` as per the documentation.

> Hammer is able to trigger DOM events with the option domEvents: true. This will give your methods like stopPropagation(), so you can use event delegation. Hammer will not unbind the bound events.

Sample Code

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(elem);
mc.options.domEvents=true; // enable dom events
var pinch = new Hammer.Pinch();
mc.add(pinch);
mc.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
mc.on("pinch",function(e){e.srcEvent.stopPropagation();});
```

or

```
var hammertime = new Hammer(elem);
hammertime.domEvents = true;
hammertime.on("panstart", function(e){e.srcEvent.stopPropagation();});
```

This technique is listed on the tips page of the docs, here http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/

Answer (score 5):

Try `event.srcEvent.stopPropagation()`.  Hammer wraps itself around the native event object; `srcEvent` gives you access to the 'usual' affordances of the event object.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, specifically that a nested Hammer component was not properly stopping propagation. In my case, I wanted a modal container (which was the highest level parent component, full screen with an opaque black background) to handle a click event that closed the whole modal. The children components hold the content and I wanted to cancel propagation with those children. In other words, the desired behavior is: a click inside the modal does nothing, but a click outside the modal closes the modal.

This is further complicated by the `react-hammerjs` library that adds an extra layer of abstraction, including [potential bug reports](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-hammerjs/issues/60) that indicate improper event propagation.

No matter what I did, I could not get `stopPropagation()` to work. Even with the `options.domEvents` set to true. I also tried digging into the `event.srcEvent.stopPropagation()` (and variants) with no success.

I found that using `stopImmediatePropagation()` works as intended, regardless of the `domEvents` setting. I understand that `stopImmediatePropagation()` may be more extreme, but I experience no side effects. Click handlers inside the children (like buttons) still work fine, and I can cancel the modal by clicking on the container.

Here's my final snippet that works fine:

```
const myComponent = (props) => (
   <Hammer onTap={() => { ... cancel modal ... }} >
      <div className={'modal-container'} >
         <Hammer onTap={(e) => e.srcEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()}>
            <div className={'modal-content'}>
               ... modal content
               <Hammer onTap={() => { ... button handler ... }}>
                  <button>Take Action</button>
               </Hammer>
            </div>
         </Hammer>
      </div>
   </Hammer>
)
```

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` worked for me, when just `stopPropagation` was not. Thank you!

Comment: At first the stopImmediatePropagation seemed to work for me too. But it ended up with side effects I couldn't explain. Once it was called once, the outer element's handler wouldn't fire, even when other clicks should have been caught by it. I ended up not using it but setting a new property within the srcEvent that a higher level could look for as it is bubbled. In one sense cleaner, in another not so. Now I have to standardize on this new property for any level above. But getting the handlers registered in the proper order was key. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `stopPropagation()` doesn't work. You need to check the target of your gesture to understand from where the event has been triggered.

For example:

```
$(parent_element).hammer().bind(gesture_type, function(event) {
    if (event.gesture.target.className === correctClass)
        doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That just works:

```
$(".outer-box").hammer({
  preventDefault: true,
  domEvents: true
}).on("panright", function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in which I had two swipe-able containers on top of each other and only wanted the top one to handle the event. For some reason, `event.srcEvent.stopPropagation` just wasn't working.

As it turns out, there exists a library that extends Hammer.js with event propagation called [propagating-hammerjs](https://github.com/josdejong/propagating-hammerjs). I pulled this into my project it fixed my problem.

Comment: That's terrible, I'll stop using HammerJs

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, however was able to handle this by enabling domEvents.

```
Hammer.defaults.domEvents = true;
```

Once enabled, event.stopPropagation(); worked fine.