# Does "use strict" offer any speed improvements?

Tags: javascript, performance, use-strict

Leaving aside possible differences stemming from code structure changes to conform with `"use strict";`, does running code in strict mode offer any speed benefits?

Comment: Great question! I am wondering what the answer will be.

Comment: Do you mean client side or Node.js?

Comment: I'm mainly interested in the client-side, that's I tagged the question with Javascript, but not with Node.js, however, if you can chip in on server-side Javascript, that would be great too.

Comment: The answer to JavaScript performance questions is almost always ***it depends*** (on what engine, on what the code is doing, on the time of day, on whether it's currently daylight savings time, on which constellation is rising in Venus...okay, some of those might have been a bit facetious).

Comment: Read this [Is strict mode more performant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145966/is-strict-mode-more-performant)

Comment: It has something todo with runtime checks I believe.

Comment: "Strict mode fixes mistakes that make it difficult for JavaScript engines to perform optimizations: strict mode code can sometimes be made to run faster than identical code that's not strict mode." ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode))