# TypeScript strict compiler option in specific files

Tags: typescript

I've recently set `strict: true` in the `tsconfig.json` of a large project. I am working through each file fixing the issues this has brought up. My problem is that I need to visually check the site as I go, but until all the issues are fixed (there's a lot) it won't build.

Is it possible to have the `strict` compiler option for only specific files, ie. the ones I've fixed, so I can build the project and check if anything's broken?

Comment: The default configuration for the compiler is to emit code when semantic erorrs are present. And `strict` will only introduce semantic errors. So you could run even with the errors

Comment: Just ensure, that `noEmitOnError` is `false`

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can place `"use strict";` directly in your `.ts` at the top of the file (i.e., before your `imports`) to set strict-mode on just that file.

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391760/use-strict-needed-in-a-typescript-file) for details and additional references.